# Is it possible to tell WINE to use OpenJDK instead of having to install Java in it

Tags: 11.10, wine, openjdk

Is it possible to make WINE use OpenJDK (Outside of the Wine environment) instead of having to install Java inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because wine is "in its own world;" it doesn't share any programs with Linux. You have to install Java inside of it, but there is no reason to because Java programs are cross-platform.